# Grid layout of divs in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a view in my application where I would like to display thumbnails in a grid layout.  When I create divs with no content they appear as desired:

[image]

When I add content to the divs, the layout goes all haywire:
[image]

I can't figure out why it is that this is happening.

I'm using a *ngFor directive for angular2:

```
    <div class="board-thumbnail-container" *ngFor="let board of boards">
      <img class="board-thumbnail" [src]="getBoardImage(board)">
      <h3><span>{{board}}</span></h3>
    </div>
```

and this is the css behind it:

```
.container {
  width:400px;
}
.board-thumbnail-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 174px;
  height: 174px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.board-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 160px;
  max-height: 160px;
}

.board-thumbnail-container > h3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.board-thumbnail-container > h3 > span {
   color: white; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
}
```

Here is a plunker exhibiting the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Trl8MJ7wuzYEgRGzy5yA?p=preview

Comment: Can you create a jsfidlle or plunker?

Comment: @ArunGhosh I have added a plunker link to the question (http://plnkr.co/edit/Trl8MJ7wuzYEgRGzy5yA?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working when I gave `vertical-align: top` to `.board-thumbnail-container`. Check http://plnkr.co/edit/HIiQrROahSMGggFWcnoX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Thought of using [angular flex layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki)?

Comment: No I have not. Looks like this is quite a recent addition to angular. I'll have to check it out!